# Failing to activate a feature using COM in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-clientobject

```
            Guid featureId = new Guid("0af5989a-3aea-4519-8ab0-85d91abe39ff");

            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://mysite:786/");

            Site clientSite = clientContext.Site;
            clientContext.Load(clientSite);

            FeatureCollection clientSiteFeatures = clientSite.Features;
            clientContext.Load(clientSiteFeatures);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            // Activate the feature
            clientSite.Features.Add(featureId, true, FeatureDefinitionScope.Site);
            //clientSiteFeatures.Remove(featureId, false); 
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Success");
```

> When I am running this code, I am getting the exception: Feature with
> id "0af5989a-3aea-4519-8ab0-85d91abe39ff" isn't installed in farm and
> can't be added to scope.
>
> I got this feature id from the link http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7695.list-of-sharepoint-2010-features-id-displayname-and-scopes.aspx
>
> Please guide.
>
> Regards,
> Vikrant Raj Behal

Answer (score 4):

```
FeatureDefinitionScope.None
```

This activated a web-scoped feature for me.

Answer (score 2):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.featurecollection.add%28v=office.15%29.aspx) the `FeatureCollection.Add`  method has the following signature

```
public Feature Add(
    Guid featureId,
    bool force,
    FeatureDefinitionScope featdefScope
)
```

which is intended for adding the feature to the collection of activated features and returns the added feature

Parameter [FeatureDefinitionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.featuredefinitionscope%28v=office.14%29.aspx)  is used for specifying the feature scope for a feature definition.
At the same time the documentation says:

> It must have the value of `FeatureDefinitionScope.Site` or
>   `FeatureDefinitionScope.Farm`

It basically means that the method `FeatureCollection.Add` does not accept `FeatureDefinitionScope.Web` value for `featdefScope`  and therefore feature activation with **Web scope** is not supported.

In your case it seems you are trying to activate feature with scope that is not supported (ex. Web) via CSOM

---

How to verify feature scope

```
$feature = get-spfeature featureId
if ($feature -eq $null -or $feature -eq "") {
    echo "no feature found with id"
} else {
  echo ("feature found. Scope is  " + $feature.Scope)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to activate a feature using the Client Object Model, It has to be deployed using a sandbox solution. Features which are deployed via Farm Solutions cannot be activated through the Client Object Model

Answer (score 0):

```
FeatureDefinitionScope.None
```

also works for activating Site Collection features.

The way a feature is added (Sandbox, Farm Solution) does not matter.